# what is the song that plays 18 minutes into episode 354 of Naruto Shippuden?

Tags: naruto, music

Naruto Shippuden
Episode 354
timestamp: 18:00/23:10

What is the music that plays in the background?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is *Naruto Shippuuden Soundtrack II*, track 25, "*Shirobae*" (translated title: "*The Rain Stops*").

It sounds like a slower, calmer, guitar version of "*Guren*", the theme that appeared a lot in many of the Yuukimaru scenes back during that Three-Tails filler arc.